# Android - Padding/Margin Exists but is not set

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

There is a left horizontal padding that exists in my app that i did not set and can't find out how to remove it, for the image i added a sample image to illustrate the issue. This is what is happening:

[image]

And here is the layout for that piece:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/actionBarLogo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/th2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It also happened on my main activity but only by about 5dp which was fine because i added 5dp on the right. But for my action bar It seems like 15dp or so and thats too much off each side. Where would it be coming from?

**EDIT**

This is how i initialize the actionable

```
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View myActionBar = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_custom, null);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layout = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(myActionBar, layout);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT**

When I try to add padding/margin to the right, the left padding/margin grows

***EDIT***

I'm not sure the difference between margin and padding but I think it could be margin instead if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove the android:orientation="vertical" (not used in a relative layout), android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" (not needed when you have match_parent width),
android:layout_gravity="center" (not used inside a relative layout), android:layout_centerHorizontal and android:layout_centerHorizontal (  android:layout_centerInParent="true" is enough).

Secondly, is this an activity layout? Do you use it directly in 'setContentView()'? Or is it inside a Fragment or inside a custom view? Any level in the view hierarchy could be causing this. You can use the layout editor in Android Studio to find what's causing it (click on the 'Design' tab when looking at the xml file, and then click on the empty padding to see where it belongs). If you can't figure it out from there, you can use the Hierarchy Viewer (http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html) on an emulator and see what's wrong.

Comment: That is an action bar but the padding situation also is caused in my mainActivity which extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: Are you using the same image in your activity? Is it possible the image has empty space on the left?

Comment: I've tried multiple images all yielding the same result